# How do I join two tables with ids and the closest next date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider I have two tables

Table A :

```
ID    Date1      Value  
A   12/12/2019  0.75
B   01/01/2020  0.2
C   02/02/2020  0.6
D   03/03/2020  0.4
E   04/04/2020  0.8
F   05/05/2020  0.9
```

and Table B :

```
ID2 Date2   Value2
A   18/12/2019  0.9
B   06/02/2020  0.6
C   08/03/2020  0.5
A   04/04/2020  0.8
B   06/07/2020  0.7
E   07/08/2020  0.5
```

I want to join them by IDs but want the dates to line up so the record for table 1 is linked with the same ID and the closest future date(associated with the ID.)

How I do join them in such a way in SQL?

I would like it to to result in something like this:

```
// ID1  DATE1     VALUE1    ID2 DaTE2   VALUE 2
// A    12/12/2019  0.75    A   18/12/2019  0.9
// B    01/01/2020  0.2     B    06/02/2020 0.6
// C    02/02/2020  0.6     C   08/03/2020  0.5
// D    03/03/2020  0.4     NULL    NULL    NULL
// E    04/04/2020  0.8     E   07/08/2020  0.5
//  F   05/05/2020  0.9     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: You'll get a better response if you remove the images and present the tables as text.

Comment: What if there are two rows in table B that have the same date, and they are both the "closest future date." Do you want both rows?

Comment: So on the database I'm trying to work with- It needs to join with the ID, and the closest future date amongst the same ID

Comment: (1) What is the "closest next date" in your example? (2) A plan: make two selects that produce rows with id, value, and "closest next date" computed, use them as sub-queries, and join them in a select.

Comment: So For example Consider ID A from Table 1- I want it to join with record 1(on table 2) and not record4 - even they are the same IDs- but because record 1's date is closer to the IDs date on table 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
select *
from A inner join B on (
    A.ID1 = B.ID2 and B.Date2 = (
        select min(sub.Date2) from B sub where sub.ID2 = A.ID1 and sub.Date2 > A.Date1)
    )
)
```

Basically, for each row in A, find the row in B where the IDs are the same and the date is minimum of all the matching dates that are in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'sub' here means

Comment: It's an alias for B within the subquery. B already appears in the outer query so I needed a different name for the subquery's B.

Answer (score 0):

TO get the closet date from table B for each record in TableA:

```
SELECT A.ID,A.`Date`, MIN(B.`Date`) AS B_Date
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID=B.ID
AND B.`Date`>A.`Date`
GROUP BY A.ID,A.`Date`


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableA;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableA (
  ID varchar(10) not null,
  `Date` date not null,
  Value decimal(5,2) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID,`Date`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableB (
  ID varchar(10) not null,
  `Date` date not null,
  Value decimal(5,2) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID,`Date`)
);

INSERT TableA(ID,`Date`,Value)
VALUES ('A', '2019-12-12', 0.75),
('B', '2020-01-01', 0.2),
('C', '2020-02-02', 0.6),
('D', '2020-03-03', 0.4),
('E', '2020-04-04', 0.8),
('F', '2020-05-05', 0.9);
INSERT TableB(ID,`Date`,Value)
VALUES ('A', '2019-12-18', 0.9),
('B', '2020-02-06', 0.6),
('C', '2020-03-08', 0.5),
('A', '2020-04-04', 0.8),
('B', '2020-07-06', 0.7),
('E', '2020-08-07', 0.5);

SELECT * FROM TableA;
SELECT * FROM TableB;

SELECT ta.*, tb.`Date` AS B_date, tb.Value as B_Value
FROM TableA ta
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A.ID,A.`Date`, MIN(B.`Date`) AS B_Date
    FROM TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.ID=B.ID
    AND B.`Date`>A.`Date`
    GROUP BY A.ID,A.`Date`) mb
ON ta.ID=mb.ID
AND ta.`Date`=mb.`Date`
LEFT JOIN TableB tb
ON tb.ID=mb.ID
AND tb.`Date`=mb.B_Date
ORDER BY ta.ID;
```

Comment: Actually- that seems to lead to replication of Table a records until it joins with all the dates of that id......

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by your comment. Can you add the expected results in your question?

Comment: Hey @PeterHE- I have added it in my question

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using a `Common Table Expression` to aggregate the earliest date for each ID in TableA first, then performing a simple SELECT on the CTE.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.ID, min(b.Date2) AS EarliestFutureData
  FROM TableA a
  JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID2
 WHERE b.Date2 > getdate()
 GROUP
    BY a.ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: This leads to a join where there are two records (for ID A) from table A(with the same date) matching with the two records in table B for ID A.